# How to get XCode to record test

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to get XCode to record for a UITest, however I select the test method to use, and XCode consistently tells me I need to select a test method.

From the below screenshot you can see the error as I hover over the record button.

Is there something I am missing here, or is it fundamentally broken and not used anymore?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

If I place the cursor within the test method, no record button is visible.

[image]

I am using XCode version
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the cursor inside of the test method by clicking inside of the function's body. Then click the record button and Xcode will record the test.

(Xcode needs to be running the app.)

Comment: Yeah, tried that, but when doing that the record button is not visible.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information. Hope it helps! 

Comment: so are you saying that launching the app from within the test is invalid?

Comment: No was just saying that to record the test Xcode needs to be running the app. If Xcode isn't running the app, clicking the record button should make that so.

Comment: Xcode crashes right away on click of the red button. Using Xcode 15.1.